# deleting data disk in linux vm return error in windows azure

Tags: linux, azure

My linux vm on windows azure has a 300 gb data disk attached to it and when I try to delete it, I get an error in portal says the disk is not attached to. In the azure portal I still see the data disk is attached to linux vm but can not delete it.

Does any one see the same problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're attempting to do?  It sounds like you have attached a disk to a VM, may have mounted it in linux, and haven't detached the disk before deleting it... Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a data disk from Windows Azure VM you would need to follow the given steps:

1. Identify where your Data Disk is physically located in specific Windows Azure Storage name and container and keep it
2. Now log into your Windows Azure VM (Linux/Windows) and unmount the data disk
3. After that you would need to detach the Data disk from Windows Azure VM configuration and this can be done via portal or using Powershell commands
4. After you detach the data disk from Windows Azure VM configuration the data disk is still listed at Virtual Machines -> Disks (Disk Type - Data Disk) section so go ahead select your specific Data Disk from the list and Delete it.
5. Step #4 will remove the VHD lease and the Data Disk will not be listed anymore in Virtual Machines -> Disks section however the VHD is still taking precious space in your Windows Azure Storage so you would need to remove it to reclaim the space.
6. To delete the VHD permanently, visit to Windows Azure Storage (you identified in step #1) using 3rd Party Azure Storage tools or any other method and then delete the VHD permanently.

Please try above steps and this should delete your Data disk from Windows Azure VM.

Comment: How are data disks priced?  I understand that different size VMs offer varying amounts of storage.  I have two small instances which only show 30gb storage.  According to microsoft i get more storage for small vms.  Where is this storage allocated? does it need to be attached as a data disk?